# What is the equivalent of this Coffescript code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
phantom = require 'phantom'

phantom.create (ph) ->
  ph.createPage (page) ->
    page.open "http://www.google.com", (status) ->
      console.log "opened google? ", status
      page.evaluate (-> document.title), (result) ->
        console.log 'Page title is ' + result
        ph.exit()
```

I tried using this website but it doesn't seem to be very accurate. It has returns everywhere.  http://js2coffee.org/#coffee2js

Comment: If you're not explicitly returning something in the js, `js2coffee` assumes that the return value doesn't matter (since you have to explicitly not return a value in coffeescript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function(ph)) {

    ph.createPage(function(page) {

        page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {

            console.log("opened google? ", status);

            page.evaluate(function() { return document.title; }, function() {

                console.log('Page title is ' + result);
                ph.exit()

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** After a second look, it does seem that some of these returns are spurious/redundant. That is because Coffeescript just always returns the result of the last statement in the function (so that you can save the `return` keyword), even in cases where you would not have returned anything in Javascript (the compiler cannot know your intention here). That may be unnecessary, but there is also no harm in it, if no one was using the return value anyway. If it is somehow important to return "nothing", you'd can explicitly do that, too.

---

You can just compile it, to see what it results in:

```
var phantom;

phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function(ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(page) {
    return page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
      console.log("opened google? ", status);
      return page.evaluate((function() {
        return document.title;
      }), function(result) {
        console.log('Page title is ' + result);
        return ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

---

> It has returns everywhere.

Well, every function you define there has one return.

One of the prime motivators for Coffeescript is to be able to write all those callback functions with less boilerplate.

Either way, the compiler is "accurate".